Can I create a module specifier from an object?
In JavaScript, we can import modules like so:
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";

where module-name is the module specifier.
If I already have an object in memory, can I "create" a module specifier from it?
Like this:
// main.js

const myObj = { text: 'Hello World' };

createModuleSpecifier(myObj, 'my-obj'); // <-- is this possible in JavaScript?

// module.js

import * as MyObj from "my-obj";

console.log(MyObj.text); // <-- this should log 'Hello World' to the console


How is main.js getting loaded into module.js?

In relation to the only language tagged in the question (javascript), what is createModuleSpecifier - either I've missed something, or

It seems that you don't want to create a module specifier, but rather create (register) a module for a given specifier.

No, there is no universal way to do this. Different runtimes implement module resolution differently, it's imaginable that some of them expose some method that does hit. What are you working with?

In short, I think that the answer depends on the environment...
I'm recommending this package:
https://github.com/single-spa/import-map-overrides
It works for browsers and NodeJS too...
You register your aliases in the main.js (or your entry point), then any other module can use that alias to import the aliased file.
